# Assign a Function Pointer to a variable

Tags: c

I have 2 files file1.c file2.c. I need to store the Function Pointers passed from file1.c to file2.c in a struct array of size 2.

```
file1.c

main ()
{
   setFuncPointer ( 1, &call_to_routine_1 );
   setFuncPointer ( 2, &call_to_routine_2 );

void call_to_routine_1 ()
{
  // Do something
}
void call_to_routine_2()
{
  // Do something
}
}

file2.c

struct store_func
{
  UINT32 Id;
  void *fn_ptr;
} func[2];

void setFuncPointer( UINT32 id, void(*cal_fun)())
{
   func[0].id = id;
   /* How to assign the cal_fun to the local fn_ptr and use that later in the code */
}
```

Also, I am unsure of declaring the void pointer inside the struct. Please suggest the right way of defining and using the callback functions defined in file1.c from file2.c

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assigning a function pointer to an object pointer like `void *` is undefined behaviour. Us the correct type for the pointers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am not sure whats the right way of assigning the function pointer locally to some variable/pointer and later using the same variable/pointer in file2.c code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside of your struct, this:

```
void *fn_ptr;
```

Should be defined as this:

```
void (*fn_ptr)(void);
```

And `setFuncPointer` should be defined as:

```
void setFuncPointer( UINT32 id, void(*cal_fun)(void))
```

Then in `setFuncPointer`, you can do this:

```
func[0].fn_ptr = cal_fun;
```

Later on, you can call the function like this:

```
func[0].fn_ptr();
```

Also, it's sufficient to call `setFuncPointer` like this:

```
setFuncPointer ( 1, call_to_routine_1 );
setFuncPointer ( 2, call_to_routine_2 );
```

Comment: @user2618994 Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: `(void)` should be used instead of `()` in the function declaration and in the function pointer type, to indicate that the function takes no parameters. `()` means *any number of parameters*, with silent undefined behaviour if the programmer doesn't match up the parameter count when calling the function.

Comment: @M.M Good catch.  Updated.